# Grails ehcache and externalizing configuration

Tags: caching, grails, config, ehcache, externalizing

I am looking at externalizing certain configuration parameters for ehcache in our Grails application and I am running into something not working that the documentation claims ought to.

Likely there is something I am missing.

I am using the grails ehcache plugin version 1.0.1 with Grails 2.4.0 and grails cache plugin 1.1.7. I am using hibernate plugin 3.6.10.16.

Here's what I have in my CacheConfig.groovy configuration...

```
...
cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory {
    peerDiscovery 'automatic'
    factoryType 'rmi'
    multicastGroupAddress '${ehcacheMulticastGroupAddress}'
    multicastGroupPort '${ehcacheMulticastGroupPort}'
    timeToLive 'site'
}
```

I've turned on debug-level logging so I can see what XML it generates. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class='net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory'
    properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,multicastGroupAddress=${ehcacheMulticastGroupAddress},multicastGroupPort=${ehcacheMulticastGroupPort},timeToLive=32"
    propertySeparator=','
/>
```

The grails ehcache plugin documentation has the following note, which I was hoping to "prove out"...

```
(note that ${ehcacheMulticastGroupAddress} and ${ehcacheMulticastGroupPort} are an Ehcache feature that lets you use system property names as variables to be resolved at runtime)
```

Great. Except that it doesn't work when I start the application. It fails to create `CacheManagerPeerProvider` due to the following

```
...
Caused by UnknownHostException: ${ehcacheMulticastGroupAddress}
->>  901 | lookupAllHostAddr        in java.net.InetAddress$1
...
```

I have a `myApplication-config.groovy` file living in an accessible area that I point to when assigning a value to `grails.config.locations` in `Config.groovy`. But I am not sure it is making any effort to really interpolate that value at all.

I tried double quotes but they were a bad idea as well -- at the time of interpreting `CacheConfig.groovy` it doesn't see the configuration I put into `myApplication-config.groovy`. I do know it reads that file in successfully at some point because I successfully use it to drive some Quartz job logic, so the placement of that config file is probably not the issue.

Comment: I'm successfully externalized my `Config.groovy` through `grails.config.locations`. And this file contains some config section from another configs (from `DataSource.groovy` for example). So, you may try externalize your EhCache settings by the same way.

Comment: You even may just specify external `CacheConfig.groovy` in `grails.config.locations` and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But I realized what I did wrong... the problem lay with my reading comprehension skills. Ehcache is looking for `system properties` not context config stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I need to set SYSTEM PROPERTIES for ehcache to find. Using Grails configuration files such as `myApplication-config.groovy` is completely incorrect.

The `CacheConfig.groovy` file is correct, as is the XML it generates. So the question becomes, how do the properties it looks for get set correctly in the first place?

I am deploying to Tomcat. For Tomcat, setting system properties makes the most sense in a `setenv.bat` file (or `setenv.sh` on *nix).

I created `setenv.bat`, put the following into it

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -DehcacheMulticastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1 -DehcacheMulticastGroupPort=4446 -DehcachePeerListenerPort=40001
```

...And it worked. Ehcache was able to find the system properties and start everything appropriately.

tl;dr: system properties != grails application config